# Update docker client on windows server 2016

Tags: windows, docker, server

Is there an way to update the docker client (powershell) on windows server 2016.
When I type "docker version" in powershell, I get the following output.

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.0-dev
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   8e92415
 Built:        Thu May 26 17:08:34 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      20.10.9
 API version:  1.41
 Go version:   go1.16.12m2
 Git commit:   9b96ce992b
 Built:        12/21/2021 21:33:06
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
```

I would like to use docker in the Windows Admin Console and have absolutely no idea about how I managed to install this old version in the first place.

I have already tried several times to reinstall docker, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that there was an old version of the binaries under system32.
After removing them it worked.

**Disclaimer:** Do not try this yourself until you are 100% sure what you are doing. Be very careful with system files and folders.